# Vite Dev Server Sourcemaps Don't Work or Point to Wrong Lines/Files in VScode Debugger

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, debugging, vite

I'm using WSL2 and/or Fedora 38 with VScode and a previously CRA project that I've converted over to Vite. Since moving to Vite I have not been able to get the VScode debugger to work correctly in both Chrome and Firefox with each browser behaving differently. The most relevant behaviors I've seen are:

- VScode is sometimes unable to bind breakpoints while debugger is active (Chrome).
- VScode slows to a complete stall when a breakpoint is placed while the debugger is active (Chrome).
- VScode or the Browser point to transformed files instead of the local files the sourcemaps point to. (Chrome/FF)
- Vite reports incorrect line numbers in stack traces (Chrome/FF).
- Breakpoints don't trigger at all (Chrome/FF).

I've been trying a myriad of options across both WSL2 and Fedora 38 in both the launch.json and Vite.config.js. My current configurations:

#### launch.json

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "trace": true,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "perScriptSourcemaps": "yes",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    {
      "name": "Firefox Debug",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "skipFiles": [
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "http://localhost:3000",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

#### vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { sentryVitePlugin } from "@sentry/vite-plugin";
import { VitePWA } from 'vite-plugin-pwa';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy'
import path from "path";

//import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';


export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  //import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
  process.env = { ...process.env, ...loadEnv(mode, process.cwd(), '')};
  
  return {
    build: {
      outDir: 'build',
      sourcemap: true
    },
    plugins: [react(), VitePWA({
      injectRegister: null,
      strategies: 'injectManifest',
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      srcDir: 'src',
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
        type: "module",
      },
      injectManifest: {
        maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 20 * 1024 * 1024,
      }
    })],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
      },
    },
    preview: {
      port: 3000
    },

    server: {
      port: 3000,
      host: "0.0.0.0"
    }
  };
});
```

Relevant GH Issue I opened: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/issues/1739#issuecomment-1629913799

Comment: I am now at 5.0 in Vite and seen multiple issues mention this type of bug but still have yet to see a valid solution as an end user.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

The problem is that the default configuration for the VSCode debugger doesn't work well with Vite. The debugger expects the source files to be located in the same directory as the transformed files, but Vite doesn't do this by default.

To fix this, you need to add the following line to your launch.json file:

```
"pathMappings": [
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "path": "${workspaceFolder}"
  }
]
```

This will tell the debugger to look for the source files in the same directory as the transformed files.

Once you've made this change, you should be able to debug your Vite project without any problems.

Here is an updated version of your launch.json file:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "trace": true,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "perScriptSourcemaps": "yes",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "http://localhost:3000",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Firefox Debug",
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "skipFiles": [
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "url": "http://localhost:3000",
          "path": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Solution 2**

Debugging in Vite with correct sourcemaps and breakpoints can sometimes be challenging, especially when using specific setups like WSL2 or non-standard configurations. To improve the debugging experience, you can try the following steps:

Ensure you have the latest versions of Vite and other related dependencies, as newer updates might include fixes for sourcemaps and debugging issues.

Modify your launch.json file:

```
For Chrome:

{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For Firefox

```
{
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Launch Firefox",
          "type": "firefox",
          "request": "launch",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "pathMappings": [
            {
              "url": "webpack:///*",
              "path": "${webRoot}/*"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Make sure you have the Vite plugin `vite-plugin-sentry` properly configured to include source maps for Sentry. This may help with sourcemap issues as well.

Check if there are any overlapping settings or conflicts between VSCode launch configurations and Vite's dev server configurations.

Verify that your Vite build configuration is generating proper sourcemaps:

```
export default {
  // Other configurations...
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
    // Other build options...
  },
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix my issue.

Comment: Please share what're facing now? Are you facing same issue or different?

Comment: Same issue, breakpoints either don't bind at all or report stack traces using transformed files despite I can use browser inspectors and see the sourcemaps correctly loaded right next to their transformed counterparts.